# Call MySQL stored procedure from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have looked at several examples on how to call a MySQL stored procedure from PHP but none have helped me. The stored procedure works when run inside PHPMyAdmin but I am having trouble calling it from the web.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"CALL standings_build()");

if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
  header('refresh:1; url=schedule_main_scores.php');
else
  echo "failed";

?>
```

Comment: you should be getting a `1` as an error here, once you used the right variable that is. Look at what you did again.

Comment: So I should change $result to $sql ?

Comment: You don't need the second `mysqli_query` at all. See @Fred-ii-s answer below, he covers everything you need to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's 2 problems here.

You're querying twice *and* using the wrong variable, being `$sql` instead of `$result`.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"CALL standings_build()");

if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^ calling the query twice
                       ^^^^ wrong variable, undefined
```

all that needs to be done is this:

```
if ($result)
```

and an `else` to handle the (possible) errors.

Error reporting and `mysqli_error($conn)` would have been your true friends.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
- http://php.net/mysqli_error

Side note: You really should use proper bracing techniques though, such as:

```
if ($result){
    echo "Success";
}

else {
    echo "The query failed because of: " . mysqli_error($conn); 
}
```

It helps during coding also and with an editor for pair matching.